# Array_filter and empty()

Tags: php, array-filter

> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'empty' not found or invalid function name....

Why is empty considered a invalid callback?

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, 'empty');
```

This works: `if(empty($arr['foo'])) die();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Answer

[`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is not a function but a language construct and `array_filter()` can only accept a function as its callback.

This is given as a small note on the manual page:

> **Note:** Because this is a language construct and not a function, it
>   cannot be called using [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

### Work around

To work around this you can wrap empty in another function for example:

```
function empty_test($val) {
    return empty($val);
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, 'empty_test');
```

Comment: +1 for the workaround. Here's something a little more creative (but much more expensive I think): `$arr = array_diff($arr, array_filter($arr));`

Comment: Nice. It is also a bit more taxing on the mind to figure out what behaviours are at play here!

Answer (score 7):

See [the documentation page on `empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Note: Because **this is a language construct and not a function**, it cannot be called using variable functions

So basically **`empty()` is not a function**, and because **callback must be a function**, **`empty()` can not be passed as callback**.

But you can create callback that may use `empty()`. The following should work in PHP > 5.3:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($var){
    return empty($var);
});
```

In PHP < 5.3 you will need to create similar function first and then pass it to the `array_filter()`.

Did it help?

Comment: If filtering out empty values just add !empty($var) as this example is filtering out not empty values, returning an array of empty values.

Answer (score 6):

[`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a language construct, and not a true function in terms of PHP, so you can't pass its name as an argument to functions like `array_filter()` and `call_user_func_array()`.

From the manual:

> **Note**: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

For a workaround, just wrap it in another user-defined function; see [Treffynnon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399867/106224).

Answer (score 0):

You can use just array_filter() function without callback:

[Remove empty array elements in PHP](https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/remove-empty-array-elements-in-php/)

```
$arr = array("PHP", "HTML", "CSS", "", "JavaScript", null, 0);
print_r(array_filter($arr)); // removing blank, null, false, 0 (zero) values
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHP
    [1] => HTML
    [2] => CSS
    [4] => JavaScript
)
```

Comment: This is the opposite of the desired effect.

Comment: hah, you're absolutely right XD